# Quartz: Multiple Jobs that share a resource

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have multiple jobs and they all share the same resource. This resource is some ad-hoc build script, and so it cannot be ran concurrently.

Is it possible to define in Quartz that some jobs cannot run concurrently?

So, if one of the jobs is already running, the spawned job is queued.

Comment: do you use spring with quartz ? or just quartz scheduler ? Could you please show your current configuration ?

Comment: @SagarVeeram. Yes, I'm using Spring Boot. I still don't have any code to show as I wanted to understand if that's the right solution before jumping to implementing

Comment: I actually know that in Spring you may schedule a task with some custom `ExectuerService`. If you set it to a `SingleThreadExecutor` it may do the work, I believe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had encounter a similar scenario in my application, try out the below approach and see if it works for you.

Put the code that runs your ad-hoc build script in a **synchronized** block.
With this only one thread will run your ad-hoc script at a time, even when multiple threads are trying to run the same resource.

With this, you can increase the thread count to a suitable value as well instead of setting it to 1, like below.
`spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=5`

If you want to run multiple quartz scheduler instances on different machines sharing a single database, then you should consider **Configure Clustering with JDBC-JobStore**. Please refer this link for more info http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.2/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html

Comment: If you have multiple machines, the job can execute on any of the machines. So `synchronized ` blocks wont work. You can instead try to lock on a shared resource. For example: A row lock in Mysql.

Comment: @TheChetan the question didn't mention that it has requirements to run multiple quartz scheduler services on different machines but considering your point I have updated my answer hope this helps.